# Build dynamic web project without Maven

Tags: java, maven, web-services, tomcat, jersey

I made a web service with Jersey in a dynamic web project. Now I want to build it, without using Maven (our professor won't let us use Maven).
I run the project on a Tomcat 9.0 server. It runs perfectly but when I access `localhost:8080/agendarest/contactos`, I get a 404 error.

Service:

```
@Path("/contactos")
public class ContactoService {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response getUsers() throws JSONException{
        List<Contacto> contactos = new ArrayList<>();
        contactos.add(new Contacto("pedro", 3434661825L));
        return Response.status(200).entity(contactos.toString()).build();
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>agendarest</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Does your professor also disallow Gradle?

Comment: Yes, he told us that we could run it without any framework, but not how...

Comment: does localhost:8080/agendarest work?  is your web app running? is the web.xml in the folder WEB-INF ?

Comment: No, it does not work, yes my web app is running and yes the web.xml is in web-inf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I needed to add init-param
So, my web.xml:

```
    <servlet>
                <servlet-name>ContactoService</servlet-name>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
                    <param-value>com.MiApp</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>ContactoService</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

And to add MiApp.java:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class MiApp extends ResourceConfig{
    public MiApp() {
        packages("com");
    }
}
```